# Statistics - Correlation between 2 sets of data

Tags: statistics, correlation

If i know the means and standard deviations of 2 sets of data, and i know the slope of the regression line, how can I find the correlation?

**edit**

Sample 1

SD: 12.37

Sample 2

SD: 7.00

Slope of regression line: 0.789

Comment: There is actually a Statistics Stack Overflow -- http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula is $$r = b_1 \frac{s_x}{s_y},$$ where $r$ is the correlation, $b_1$ is the slope, and $s_x$ and $s_y$ are the standard deviations of the independent $(x)$ and dependent $(y)$ variables, respectively.

A reference is Wikipedia's page on [simple linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Fitting_the_regression_line).  See the formula for $\hat{\beta}$.

Comment: so the means don't matter if i already know the standard deviations?

Comment: also i'm getting a value > 1 when I use that formula...must be something wrong ?

Comment: @Sev: The means are part of the slope calculation.  So all the information you need from the means to find the correlation is already contained in the slope.

Comment: @Sev: What are your numbers for the standard deviations and the slope?  (Edit them in to your original question.)

Comment: @Mike: done....

Comment: @Sev: There must be a calculation error somewhere, since (as you pointed out) you can't have $r > 1$.  Try rechecking your calculations.  Or did you regress Sample 1 on Sample 2 rather than Sample 2 on Sample 1?

Comment: I'm going to assume something is wrong with the data.  thanks for the help!